# IntelliJ does not find pom.xml file

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I'm new to this weird `Maven` thing and unsure how it works. My project contains a valid `pom.xml` file, but I am unable to do anything with it. Basically, I go to `File -> Project Structure -> Libraries -> From Maven...` and write `pom.xml` in this search field, but it does not find anything! I'm pretty sure I am doing something wrong. In general, I just want to know how to download all the libraries into a `.jar` format.
I use `IntelliJ`and my `pom.xml` looks like this:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.corundumstudio.socketio</groupId>
    <artifactId>netty-socketio</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>bundle</packaging>
    <name>ConnectFour</name>
    <description>A connectfour website</description>
    <inceptionYear>2018</inceptionYear>

    <scm>
        <url>scm:git:git@github.com:mrniko/netty-socketio.git</url>
        <connection>scm:git:git@github.com:mrniko/netty-socketio.git</connection>
        <developerConnection>scm:git:git@github.com:mrniko/netty-socketio.git</developerConnection>
        <tag>HEAD</tag>
    </scm>

    <licenses>
        <license>
            <name>Apache v2</name>
            <url>http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html</url>
            <distribution>manual</distribution>
        </license>
    </licenses>

    <developers>
        <developer>
            <id>mrniko</id>
            <name>Nikita Koksharov</name>
            <email>abracham.mitchell@gmail.com</email>
            <roles>
                <role>Architect</role>
                <role>Developer</role>
            </roles>
            <timezone>+4</timezone>
        </developer>
    </developers>

    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>repo1</id>
            <name>Release</name>
            <url>file://C:/123</url>
        </repository>
    </distributionManagement>

    <properties>
        <skipTests>true</skipTests>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>release-sign-artifacts</id>
            <activation>
                <property>
                    <name>performRelease</name>
                    <value>true</value>
                </property>
            </activation>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
            <artifactId>netty-buffer</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.22.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
            <artifactId>netty-common</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.22.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
            <artifactId>netty-transport</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.22.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
            <artifactId>netty-handler</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.22.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
            <artifactId>netty-codec-http</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.22.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
            <artifactId>netty-codec</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.22.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
            <artifactId>netty-transport-native-epoll</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.22.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jmockit</groupId>
            <artifactId>jmockit</artifactId>
            <version>1.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.21</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.9.2</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>[2.5,)</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>[2.5,)</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.redisson</groupId>
            <artifactId>redisson</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.hazelcast</groupId>
            <artifactId>hazelcast-client</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.3</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongodb-driver-async</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.3</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>attach-javadocs</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.3</version>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9</version>
                <configuration>
                    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                    <forceRecheck>true</forceRecheck>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>verify</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>pmd</goal>
                            <goal>cpd</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <minimumTokens>100</minimumTokens>
                    <targetJdk>1.8</targetJdk>
                    <verbose>true</verbose>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.11</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>verify</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>checkstyle</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <consoleOutput>true</consoleOutput>
                    <enableRSS>false</enableRSS>
                    <configLocation>/checkstyle.xml</configLocation>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <optimize>true</optimize>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>attach-sources</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>


            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.20.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <argLine>-Dfile.encoding=utf-8</argLine>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.0</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <instructions>
                        <Bundle-Name>${project.artifactId}</Bundle-Name>
                        <Import-Package>
                            org.springframework.*;resolution:=optional,com.hazelcast.*;resolution:=optional,org.redisson.*;resolution:=optional,*
                        </Import-Package>
                        <Export-Package>
                            com.corundumstudio.socketio;version="${project.version}",
                            com.corundumstudio.socketio.annotation;version="${project.version}",
                            com.corundumstudio.socketio.listener;version="${project.version}",
                            com.corundumstudio.socketio.protocol;version="${project.version}",
                            com.corundumstudio.socketio.store;version="${project.version}",
                            com.corundumstudio.socketio.store.pubsub;version="${project.version}",
                        </Export-Package>
                    </instructions>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.mycila</groupId>
                <artifactId>license-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <basedir>${basedir}</basedir>
                    <header>${basedir}/header.txt</header>
                    <quiet>false</quiet>
                    <failIfMissing>true</failIfMissing>
                    <aggregate>false</aggregate>
                    <includes>
                        <include>src/**</include>
                    </includes>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>target/**</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                    <useDefaultExcludes>true</useDefaultExcludes>
                    <mapping>
                        <java>JAVADOC_STYLE</java>
                    </mapping>
                    <strictCheck>true</strictCheck>
                    <useDefaultMapping>true</useDefaultMapping>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>check</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of things that could be going here but try this first:

Try `ctrl-shift-a` -> "Reimport All Maven Projects"

OR

Views -> Tool Windows -> Maven Projects -> click top left button (looks like a refresh icon)

Comment: Now you accept this answer and ask another Q highlighting your new found issues. Or go off and do some research on your own.

Comment: It would seem as if IntelliJ compiled the file. No errors are shown anymore. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

First of all be sure that your project it is using Maven ?! maybe it is using Gradle so on

For a Maven project,   pom.xml file:

For a Gradle project, build.gradle file:

Alternatives to Apache Maven. Jira, Jenkins, Gradle, Apache Ant, and Apache Tomcat

Comment: The user indicates that it's a maven project, and that it has a pom.xml file. Simply listing alternative tools doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

right click the pom, choose maven and then unignore project